Triforce crossword


Across:



#
Clue




1
"Boiled stone"


2
A type of interpolation


3
A shorter word for illogicality


6
These often reside at the bottom




Diagonal up:



#
Clue




1
A very enthusiastic weapon modifier in Terraria


2
An inanimate bipedal


3
A rather peculiar bed that is used for transportation


6
That which is famously not a bug




Diagonal down:



#
Clue




4
One 16th in the company of four 8th ones


5
A word that can describe Mrs. Incredible


7
One would probably be advised to have some of it if walking down the street wearing only socks, or a hat


8
If you picture a pencil as a sword, these often serve as its pommel





Across:

 ZEOLITE BICUBIC FALLACY FEEDERS

Diagonal up:

 ZEALOUS BICYCLE FLATBED FEATURE

Diagonal down:

 SULFATE (SO₄) ELASTIC DECENCY ERASERS


 


Aaaah it was bicubic interpolation, that makes more sense. Sniped but yours was correct, I'll update mine but yours was correct first so should get the checkmark!

@BeastlyGerbil Well you are officially my first sniper, this definitely feels weird when you finally wrap up your answer and realize someone else just posted it. Also we have diverging interpretations for Across,6 I wonder which one was intended by OP

@BeastlyGerbil - I feel bad for accepting this answer but their answer does not have mistakes. It is indeed bicycle/bicubic pair of words that was missing from your answer.

@Fluorine - about across 6 - I had aquatic bottom feeders in mind. This works however, somehow :)

@webadventurer no problem at all, this is factually the first correct answer so all good! I just thought micycle was supposed to be a pun or something :P

Solution:

 


Clues:

Across:

1: "Boiled stone" - ZEOLITE (A stone that boils)
2: A type of interpolation - BICUBIC
3: A shorter word for illogicality - FALLACY
6: These often reside at the bottom - FEEDERS (Bottom of food chain)

Diagonal Up:

1: A very enthusiastic weapon modifier in Terraria - ZEALOUS (Name of a modifier)
2: An inanimate bipedal - BICYCLE
3: A rather peculiar bed that is used for transportation - FLATBED (Type of truck)
6: That which is famously not a bug - FEATURE (It's not a bug, it's a feature)

Diagonal Down:

4: One 16th in the company of four 8th ones - SULFATE (Chemical compound is S (16th element) and 4 Os (8th element)
5: A word that can describe Mrs. Incredible - ELASTIC
7: One would probably be advised to have some of it if walking down the street wearing only socks, or a hat - DECENCY
8: If you picture a pencil as a sword, these often serve as its pommel - ERASERS

